# Can I eliminate 1 switch from a 3-4-4-4-3 way configuration?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

The 2 story foyer  light is controlled by 5 switches.  1 is a dimmer at bottom of stairs.   1 at top of stairs. And 1 switch at each of 3 doors entering lower foyer.

We want to hang a large mirror on one wall.  This would hang over top of a single gang switch.

The pictures below show the switch from the left and right side view.

I want to eliminate this switch and put a blank cover over it.

[image]
[image]

Is it a simple matter to do this?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I will when I get back to the house on Monday.   Is it safe to assume the dimmer switch is the #1 switch in the sequence?

Comment: It's fairly safe to assume the dimmer will be at one end or the other of the sequence

Comment: Should be able to do it if it is one of the 4 way. If it is a 3 way, no way

Comment: Are those photos of the same switch, or of different switches?

Comment: Two sides of one switch

Comment: This isn't the switch at the top of the stairs, right?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  no sir. It is at one of the downstairs door ways. Rarely used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Go ahead and yank it

Since this is not one of the required switches for the stairwell lighting, and a 4-way, it's pretty easy to remove.  Simply nut the two black wires together and the two white wires together after removing the switch, then put a blank single gang cover plate over the box, turn the breaker on, and hang your mirror.

Comment: Hi TPE.  I yanked that 4 way and connected the wires like you said. I now have a 3way and two 4 ways left. When I turn one of the 4 ways off it kills the 3 way and other 4 way.  When I turn it back on the other 2 function as they should. What am I missing?

Comment: @Kris -- that sounds like one of the wirenut jobs was bad, make sure to crank it down tight, or use lever-nut type connectors if you aren't confident with your wirenutting abilities

Comment: I’m 99.9% sure that the wire nutting is fine.  Is it possible that I have the 3 way in the wrong location?

Comment: @Kris -- are you forgetting about the other 3-way?

Comment: The set up before was 1 3way and 3 4way.  I eliminated 1 4way

Comment: @Kris -- just because you don't use the other 3way doesn't mean it doesn't exist

Comment: I don’t understand. There is only one three way involved.   By front door a four way switch   Bottom of stairs a three way.  Top of stairs a four way.  Removed four way at foyer/living room door

Comment: I see that I posted there were initially 5 switches. I was wrong there were only 4

Comment: I counted a switch at a library door as being involved but it was not.

Comment: I think I will ask a new question with the correct number of switches.

Comment: @Kris -- yeah, a new question would be a good idea at this point, we'll need photos of the insides of *all* the boxes involved though

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so long as you are removing a 4-way. You just need to (turn off the breaker first!!!!)  tie the two inputs to the two outputs at that box -- doesn't even matter which goes to which.  Use proper-sized wire nuts, and as you suggested, put a cover on the box.  It is a code violation to leave the box inaccessible, so don't plaster or drywall over the cover.

If you want to remove a 3-way,  I strongly recommend you replace the next 4Way in line with a 3way, leading to a   3-4-4-3 sequence.  Tie the hot line into one of the output lines from the 3way you're removing, and cap off the other output line there AND as it enters the 4way location which you are changing to a 3way.  Drop the 3way into that location and you're done.
(BTW, you could use the existing 4way by simply disconnecting the 'dead' input to it from the former 3way location.  That may violate code, so check with a local electrician first)

Comment: Thanks I added pictures of the switch     How will I know which switch  is next in line?